# Populate Object Array of Shows

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Why is this not working.  The following is my code:

```
private static void FillCatalogue()
         {
         int intCatalogueNumber = 0;
         arrMyShows = new Show[intCatalogueNumber];

         Show newShow = new Show();
         //arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber] = newShow;
         Console.Clear();
         Console.Write("Title: ");
         arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].Title = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Write("Year: ");
         arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.Write("Lead Actor: ");
         arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].LeadActor = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Write("Price: ");
         arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].RentalPrice =        Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
         //Console.Write("Does the show have Blu-Ray discs?  (Y/N) ");

         Console.WriteLine(arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].Title + " " + arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].Year + " " + arrMyShows[intCatalogueNumber].LeadActor);
```

Comment: any exception? please make the `not working` more specific.

Comment: im not getting any exceptions.  It goes to the break point when running the program.

Comment: I cant figure out the exception

Comment: My fault "index out of range".  Why is it out of range?

Comment: At which line? You should also talk a little about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your array `arrMyShows` have a size of 0; of course this is not going to work. Give it another value:

```
int intCatalogueNumber = 0;
int size = SOMETHING;
arrMyShows = new Show[size];
```

Comment: Thank you.  Its always the easy little things that get me